# How to use 'post' in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please help me
I have created a controller `'users'` with a view `'login'` with a form to login users, I have changed the `routes.rb` changing `get user/login` to `post user/login`

now when I go to `localhost:3000/users/login` appears:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/users/login"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

please what should to do to works that page, that problem is because I have changed 'get' to 'post' in the routers, there are something more that I should to add?

Comment: This post is perfectly in line with what we expect here at SO. Don't abuse your downvote privilege and responsibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just go to that url in your browser, the type of request is `GET` - but, as you said, there's no route for this request now.

`POST` route will be useful when you actually submit a form on this page - with simple submit (specify `method` attribute as `POST`) or AJAX request.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on what you _want_ to do? One possible way is creating a separate route for GET action.

Comment: to a form that is used to login or register, should I to use 'get' or 'post'? please

Answer (score 1):

You can use both in routes.rb:

```
get user/login
post user/login
```

This means that the controller will recognize requests made using both methods.  It is up to your controller logic to sort it out.  The get would typically be used to render the login form; post would receive the user's username and password, authenticate him/her, and then redirect to a page for successful login (or unsuccessful, if necessary).

I may spark some controversy by saying this but if you are a beginner and you are looking to make a "serious" web site with user authentication, you may not want to leave anything up to chance and instead use a gem like devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to do it for you.  Some will say that it's better to learn how to do it from scratch first, and there's some sense in that, too.